# Codeigniter 404 Error on Bluehost

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

So I installed Codeigniter in a sub directory on my bluehost hosting account after testing it locally and everything working great! But now when I goto the subdirectory on bluehost I get taken to the right index page which is set in my routes as this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "user";
```

So that works. But when I try to go to any other page for instance.."/user/reg_view". It gives me nothing but 404 errors. I've tried different things on the htaccess file and I've also tried changing the URI protocol in the config to AUTO and also REQUEST_URI but nothing works. It just always gives me a 404 error.. any thoughts or suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: never mind I figured it out. It was how I had the rewrite rule. forgot to add in the subdirectory.

Comment: Please post a detailed answer below or delete this question.  Thanks.

Comment: @Robert hi i have a same problem please post answer otherwise help me how to resolved.